# wpf 2 pages on window

Tags: c#, wpf, navigation, window

When I press a button (or enter in a text) I would like to load up content on the right side of the window. the picture below should clarify it a lot.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/VnW6E.png

use case: user wants to see all tickets, he pushes the button show and on the right side of the window appear all the tickets. 
if he presses another button other content appears.

Right now I have a grid on the left side of the window.

could this visual design be achieved with a page on the right side of the window? And if not, is there another way?

If I could implement this, which part of the documentation is usefull to go through?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a frame and load your content into it:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Grid Grid.Column="0">
        //<!-- Show button + other controls -->
    </Grid>

    //<!-- The frame in which to show the tickets / content -->
    <Frame x:Name="FrmTickets" Grid.Column="1"/>
</Grid>
```

Make a new page and use this to display the tickets.
To display the tickets in the frame, set the frame content to the page like so

```
FrmTickets.Content = new TicketsPage();
```

In the same way, you can have another page with other content that is displayed when the user clicks another button,

```
FrmTickets.Content = new OtherContentPage();
```